# Broadcast Receiver receive information only once

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a service which sends two broadcasts at the same time.

```
val i = Intent(PlayerService.INTENT_ACTION)
i.putExtra(EVENT_EXTRAS, PlayerEvent.PLAYER_READY.ordinal)
i.putExtra(DURATION_EXTRAS, mp.duration) //some duration
sendBroadcast(i)

val i1 = Intent(PlayerService.INTENT_ACTION)
i1.putExtra(EVENT_EXTRAS, PlayerEvent.ON_SECOND_CHANGED.ordinal)
i1.putExtra(DURATION_EXTRAS, player.duration) //another duration
sendBroadcast(i1)
```

The action of intents is the same, but the extras is different. Finally, I only get the answer from the second broadcast. Who knows what the cause is?

My Receiver Live Data:

```
class PlayerLiveEvent(val context: Context) : LiveData<Intent>() {

override fun onActive() {
    super.onActive()
    context.registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter(PlayerService.INTENT_ACTION))
}

override fun onInactive() {
    super.onInactive()
    context.unregisterReceiver(receiver)
}

private val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        postValue(intent)
    }
  }
}
```

Fragment where I observe these events:

```
PlayerLiveEvent(activity!!).observe(this, Observer {
        it?.apply {
            val event = PlayerEvent.values()[getIntExtra(EVENT_EXTRAS, 0)]
            when (event) {
                PlayerEvent.PLAYER_READY -> {
                    println("PLAYER_READY")
                }
                PlayerEvent.ON_SECOND_CHANGED -> {
                    println("ON_SECOND_CHANGED")
                }
                else -> println()
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: you can achieve only single broadcast , share your code where you receive broadcast.

Comment: It should work as expected. I have used broadcast receiver inside chat app (which fires broadcast very fast). Can you post your register receiver code?

Comment: I've added the receiver code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second `onReceive` is called before a `postValue` task from the first `onReceive` is executed on the main thread and hence the value set the second time is ignored. You can also see this from the implementation of `postValue`:

```
    ...
    synchronized (mDataLock) {
        // for your second call this will be false as there's a pending value
        postTask = mPendingData == NOT_SET;
        mPendingData = value;
    }
    // so this is true and so the method returns prematurely
    if (!postTask) {
        return;
    }
    ...
```

Thereof, use `setValue` because it sets the value immediately and is called from the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in LiveData, the events are not being transmitted as needed.

This [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData#postValue(T)) explains why postValue posts only once. That is why the solution would be the following:

```
private val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        value = intent
    }
}
```